# Mirrored TDE DB Performance

Tags: sql-server-2014, mirroring, transparent-data-encryption

Performing a large index reorg on a mirrored SQL Server 2014 TDE database creates a large redo log on the mirror and the mirroring monitor displays an infinite restore time.  The exact same process with the database without TDE keeps up in near real time.

I don't expect the exact performance with TDE enabled, but the difference is night and day. Am I missing a setting or are my expectations unrealistic?  Any advice or links is much appreciated.

Comment: Why not try using an Availability Group? [Mirroring is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/2014/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Deprecated is a funny word at MS, but I would consider a different solution on a newer version.  For now, the solution requires 1 Enterprise license and it just has to work with the parameters given.  Not a single search result finds anything worthy with TDE and mirroring.